# Vimeo Content Security Policy error - Refused to load the script

Tags: video, embed, vimeo

When I'm trying to embed video from vimeo to my site, I get error in chrome console -

> Refused to load the script 'data:application/javascript;base64,dmFyIHVyY2hpblRyYWNrZXI9ZnVuY3Rpb24oKXt9…RUcmFja2VyQnlOYW1lOiBmdW5jdGlvbigpe190cmFja0V2ZW50OiBmdW5jdGlvbigpe319fTs=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://f.vimeocdn.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://f.vimeocdn.com".

I get same error in all sites, thats contains vimeo player.
For example - https://player.vimeo.com/video/174560759

That error crash my javascript, which communicate with Vimeo player API.

Maybe somebody knows, what's wrong with Vimeo, and how I can resolve this problem?

P.S. Firefox just shows me warning in console, and my js works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this error to be caused by the uBlock Origin extension. It may also be triggered by others like AdBlock.

Try browsing in Incognito or starting Chrome without extensions to see if the problem persists.